# Can't view logs in the log viewer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, google-compute-engine, stackdriver

Followed the [guide](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/ruby) (GCE)  to set up the Rails application to get the logs.
But I could only able to view the syslogs in the Logging viewer.
And while running the following command in Rails console, 
`Rails.logger` 
The google cloud instance object is returning positively.

```
Followed the steps to interact with the Google Cloud Library
`
## Imports the Google Cloud client library
       require "google/cloud/logging"

## Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
       project_id = "test-rails"

## Instantiates a client
       logging = Google::Cloud::Logging.new project: my_proid_56678

## Prepares a log entry
      entry = logging.entry
## The data to log
      entry.payload = "Hello, world!"
## The name of the log to write to
      entry.log_name = "Dashboard log"
## The resource associated with the data
      entry.resource.type = "global"

## Writes the log entry
      logging.write_entries entry

puts "Logged #{entry.payload}" `

### But, the above lines are not been reflected in Logs viewer
```

Comment: Probably editing the logs is not enough and you may need to save the edits too?

Comment: Did you also followed the instructions specific for Compute Engine mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/ruby#run-gce)

Comment: @rsalinas Yes, followed the same steps